# simplify CTE query

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I have a data structure where various data elements can be related to one another. One record can be the parent of many child records, but a child record can only have one parent. I'm working on a query to check these record 'families' to see if they are all marked obsolete, such that I can delete them.

To solve this, I wrote a CTE that starts at bottom-most child records, and works up the tree, recording the status, to end up with a 'family' status at the top level record.

One issue I ran into with this approach was when a record has multiple children, I ended up with multiple records for the top level parent. In some cases, one child path could be eligible for deletion, but the other was not. I could not come up with a way to identify this in the CTE, and ended up with a subquery, where I count the number of paths that are delete eligible and are not, then only return records with > 1 'delete' paths and 0 'don't delete' paths.

Here is my code, complete with example data

```
create table #demand (id int, [status] varchar(10))
create table #relation (parent int, child int)

insert into #demand values (1, 'active')
insert into #demand values (2, 'obsolete')
insert into #demand values (3, 'obsolete')
insert into #demand values (4, 'obsolete')
insert into #demand values (5, 'active')
insert into #demand values (6, 'obsolete')

insert into #relation values(2, 3)
insert into #relation values(2, 4)
insert into #relation values(4, 5)

--the CTE splitFamily traverses the split family records from bottom up, checking that each record is Obsolete. If any record is not
;with
splitFamily as (
    select 
        D.id, 
        DR.child,
        case when D.[status] = 'obsolete' then 'Y' else 'N' end as CanDelete
    from #demand D
    left outer join #relation DR on D.id = DR.parent
    where DR.child is null

    union all

    select
        D.id, 
        DR.child,
        case when D.[status] = 'obsolete' and splitFamily.CanDelete = 'Y' then 'Y' else 'N' end as CanDelete
    from
        splitFamily
    join #relation DR on splitFamily.id = DR.child
    join #demand D  on DR.parent = D.id
)
select id from (
    select parentLevel.id,
    sum(case when parentLevel.CanDelete = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end) as "Y",
    sum(case when parentLevel.CanDelete = 'N' then 1 else 0 end) as "N"
    from splitFamily parentLevel
    --The following join ensures we only return top level parent records to be deleted. 
    left join splitFamily children on parentLevel.id = children.child
    where children.id is null
    group by parentLevel.id
) as splits where Y > 0 and N = 0

drop table #demand
drop table #relation
```

This code works, and outputs record 6 as the only eligible delete record. If record 5 is changed to 'obsolete', the query correctly includes 2 in the results.

My question is about whether there is a cleaner, clearer way to identify those split paths within the CTE, so as to avoid the extra subquery and the counting of the paths. To me, this obfuscates the purpose of the code, and make it considerably harder to maintain going forward.

Comment: so when can you delete a node?  Is that when it is obsolete and none of its children are not-obsolete, then none of the children's children are not obsolete etc...?  Is that the rule?

Comment: @AndrewDeighton correct. The top level node and ALL related children must be in an 'obsolete' status. Then, I want to return the id of the top level node. (my deletion procedure will recurse down to delete the entire family within a single transaction)

Comment: So, essentially, once you find a delete as you are traversing down your hierarchy, you want to stop so you can report out that node? Like... at that point you don't care about the descendants, right?

Comment: As you mention, query works so this should be asked on [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as folks there will eat your question up with excellent comment to optimize since so few questions are asked on the site compared to here. Second page for some tags like [sql] go to 2 months ago, not 2 hours ago!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing my final select to the following. Using window functions, I was able to avoid the confusing summations, and in my mind, the select is much clearer now. The `FIRST_VALUE` function ensures that 'N' is returned if any rows had N for each `id`.

```
select distinct id from (
    select parentLevel.id,
    FIRST_VALUE(parentLevel.CanDelete) over(partition by parentLevel.DemandId order by parentLevel.CanDelete) as CanDelete
    from splitFamily parentLevel
    left join splitFamily children on parentLevel.id = children.child
    where children.id is null
) as splits where CanDelete = 'Y'
```